# How to know the vertical scrolling direction in android i.e. upward or downward

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scroll

Is there any way to determine that Android (vertical) scroll-view is scrolled **upward** or **downward**. I actually have a scenario to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The onScrollChanged event will fire, and you can compare the previous and current scroll positions.  See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29